# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row (Laravel 6)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What am I doing wrong?

Environment:
Laravel 6, Homestead (Local), Windows 10

Create External Table (Migration):

```
Schema::create('external', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('id')->references('order_id')->on('order');
            });
```

Create Order Table (Migration):

```
Schema::create('order', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('order_id')->index();
```

External.php (model):

```
class External extends Model
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Order.php (Model):

```
public function external()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(External::class);
}
```

Error Message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`external`, CONSTRAINT `external_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `order` (`order_id`)) (SQL: insert into `external` (`site_order_id`, `order_status`,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a common one, and easy to explain.  Your Laravel code is generating one (or more) insert which is referring to a record in the `order` table which does not exist.  Try running the following query:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM [order] o
WHERE order_id = <external.id value here>
```

If you get back an empty result set, then it means your insert is referring to data in `order` which does not exist.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think I fixed it.. I'll use that as a way to debug in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Edited (External Table Migration):

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('id')->references('order_id')->on('order');
```

Edited (Order Table Migration):

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id')->index()->unsigned();
```