# Laravel 6 - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I'm planning to send `id` on `supplier` to `transaction_in`

but i have this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`database_name`.`transaction_ins`, CONSTRAINT
>   `transaction_ins_supplier_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`Supplier_id`)
>   REFERENCES `suppliers` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into
>   `transaction_ins` (`Supplier_id`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (0, 2019-10-21 07:54:15, 2019-10-21
>   07:54:15))

This is `transaction_in` migration table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transaction_ins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->date('tanggal_transaksi');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('Supplier_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            //Foreign Key
            $table->foreign('Supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

`transaction_in` model

```
class Transaction_in extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function suppliers(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
    }
}
```

This is `supplier` migration table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nama');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

`supplier` model

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function transactions_in(){
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction_in::class);
    }
}
```

I already try solution from [SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row (Laravel 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056073/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-chi)

When I run the query from accepted answer it does return empty, but I don't understand this part

> If you get back an empty result set, then it means your insert is
>   referring to data in `order` which does not exist.

But the data does exist in `supplier` table

[image]

What should i do to fix this?

This is `create.blade.php` for `transaction_in`

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'TransactionsINController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('supplier_name', 'Supplier Name') }}
            {{ Form::select('supplier_name', $supplierList->pluck('nama'), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pick one Supplier...']) }}
        </div>
        <hr>
        {{ Form::button('<i class="far fa-save"></i> Submit', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-info'] )  }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and this is the `store` method on `transaction_in` controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'supplier_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $transaction_in = new Transaction_in();
        $transaction_in->Supplier_id = $request->input('supplier_name');
        $transaction_in->save();
    }
```

Comment: the answer from that question you are referring to is demonstrating to you that you do not have a `supplier` matching the `id` you are trying to assign to `Supplier_id` it would seem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select needs a list keyed by what the options value is supposed to be:

```
Form::select('supplier_id', $supplierList->pluck('nama', 'id'), null, ....);
```

Adjusted the input name to be more accurate.

> `Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], ...);`
>
> [LaravelCollective - HTML - Drop-Down Lists](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#drop-down-lists)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - `pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck)